# JS var inside query does not work when stringed together

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains

I have the following code which is really bloated

```
$(".field-name-field-parts-status .field-item:contains('Submitted'), .field-name-field-parts-status .field-item:contains('Saved'), .field-name-field-parts-status .field-item:contains('HMNZ Approved')").addClass('btn-primary');
```

I tried to neaten it up by adding a `var`

```
var fieldItemStatus = $(".field-name-field-parts-status .field-item");
```

So it looked like this

```
$(fieldItemStatus + ":contains('Submitted'), " + fieldItemStatus + ":contains('Saved'), " + fieldItemStatus + ":contains('HMNZ Approved')").addClass('btn-primary');
```

But it stopped working, can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick answers, and  .filter( ) is definitely the way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to add a jQuery object and a string together. It does not work like that.

```
var fieldItemStatus = $(".field-name-field-parts-status .field-item");
```

should be a string

```
var fieldItemStatus = ".field-name-field-parts-status .field-item";
```

other option is to use filter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `filter` method:

```
fieldItemStatus.filter(":contains('Submitted'), :contains('Saved'), :contains('HMNZ Approved')").addClass('btn-primary');
```

Another option is using the `filter` callback function:

```
var items = ['Submitted', 'Saved', 'HMNZ Approved'];
fieldItemStatus.filter(function(_, el) {
   return items.some(function(item) {
      return el.textContent.indexOf(item) > -1;
   });  
});
```

.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .filter()

```
fieldItemStatus.filter(":contains('Submitted'), :contains('Saved'), :contains('HMNZ Approved')").addClass('btn-primary');
```

`fieldItemStatus` is an object so 
`fieldItemStatus + ":contains('Submitted'), " + fieldItemStatus + ":contains('Saved'), " + fieldItemStatus + ":contains('HMNZ Approved')` will create a string like `[Object object]:contains('Submitted'), [Object object]:contains('Saved'), [Object object]:contains('HMNZ Approved')`

Answer (score 1):

remove $ in front for fieldItemStatus

```
 var fieldItemStatus = ".field-name-field-parts-status .field-item";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to use a jQuery Object to concat string. The right way to do this is using string all the time.

```
var fieldItemStatus = ".field-name-field-parts-status .field-item";
$(fieldItemStatus + ":contains('Submitted'), " + fieldItemStatus + ":contains('Saved'), " + fieldItemStatus + ":contains('HMNZ Approved')").addClass('btn-primary');
```

Answer (score 0):

A more procedural approach. This way if you want to easily change the selectors, just change the contains array. You could turn this into a function to easily retrieve your selector on demand elsewhere in the script.

```
var contains = ['Submitted','Saved','HMNZ Approved'];
var selector = '';
for(var i = 0; i < contains.length; i++) {
    selector += '.field-name-field-parts-status .field-item:contains("' + contains[i] + ')';
    if(i < contains.length - 1) selector += ', ';
}
$(selector).addClass('btn-primary');
```